Why is GridDB returning inconsistent query results with large-scale parallel writes?
I’m using GridDB in a distributed environment to handle high-volume data writes and queries simultaneously. While testing the system under load, I encountered an issue where query results are inconsistent during parallel write operations.
the scenario:

Cluster Configuration: 5-node GridDB cluster.
Data Type: Time-series data stored in containers.
Storage: Using SSDs with default persistence and replication settings.
Version: GridDB 4.6.1.

Steps to Reproduce:

Create a container for sensor data:

CREATE TIME_SERIES temperature_data (
    timestamp TIMESTAMP,
    sensor_id STRING,
    temperature DOUBLE
);


Simultaneously run:

import threading
import griddb_python as griddb

def insert_data(container, data):
    for record in data:
        container.put(record)

# Connect to GridDB
factory = griddb.StoreFactory.get_instance()
gridstore = factory.get_store(
    host="127.0.0.1",
    port=10001,
    cluster_name="defaultCluster",
    username="admin",
    password="admin"
)
container = gridstore.get_container("temperature_data")

# Generate data and write in parallel
threads = []
for i in range(10):
    data = [(f"2024-12-19T{i}:{j}:00", f"sensor_{i}", 25 + i * 0.1) for j in range(100)]
    thread = threading.Thread(target=insert_data, args=(container, data))
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

• A separate thread querying the data:
query = "SELECT * FROM temperature_data WHERE sensor_id = 'sensor_5';"
rs = container.query(query).fetch()
for row in rs:
    print(row)


Monitor the results of the query during the write operations.
While the write operations are ongoing, the query occasionally returns.

INFO: Received write requests for container 'temperature_data'.  
WARNING: Write conflict detected for partition 3. Retrying operation.  
INFO: Query executed: SELECT * FROM temperature_data WHERE sensor_id = 'sensor_5';  

ERROR: Partition 3 replication delayed due to high write load.  
INFO: Temporary inconsistency observed in container 'temperature_data'.  


Is GridDB designed to handle concurrent high-volume writes and queries without compromising consistency?

How can I configure GridDB to ensure that query results remain consistent during heavy write operations?

Are there specific tuning parameters or architectural considerations to handle this scenario effectively?


